# node.js - replace PHP, and asynchronously connect to it

Tags: node.js

Recently I started playing with node.js.

Since I'm developing a web app, I was interested in the benefits of google's javascript V8 engine, i started reading stuff about all this - and node.js.

An example of a webapp which uses node.js: http://bodesigns.com/simple-web-app-using-node-js/

As you can see, it uses node.js to connect to a mysql database. Some questions about this:
- First of all, is this safe? I mean: the username and password are stored in the file. I know, in PHP it is to, but a PHP-file is server-side. Node.js is server-side?

- Second, with this (i'm also building a part of the web app with google maps stuff), i could replace the PHP-code I have now to collect some data from a mysql database? What are the (dis)advantages of replacing the PHP-code with node.js code?
- Last: can I run a node.js server asynchronously? I mean: i have a HTML-page with a link (). When i click it, it must "run" the node.js-script, which collects data form the mysql-database. Like in the example. So when the page loads, only an empty map has to be visible. If you click something, markers have to show or hide. Is this possible?
- My apologies for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

> First of all, is this save?

node.js runs on the server, the code doesn't need to go to the client so it's safe.

> What are the (dis)advantages of replacing the PHP-code with node.js code?

Do you need to rewrite code *that already works?* If your writing new code then PHP vs node.js is a completely different and *application specific* discussion. For generic applications they are both suitable

> Is this possible?

Yes, however it's also possible with PHP.

Comment: Last question: how is it possible to run PHP-code asynchronously? Or do you mean AJAX?

Comment: @v3rt1g0 I meant ajax. But you can also run PHP asynchronously if you link a non blocking IO library

Comment: I think you are mixing up asynchronous AJAX requests with the event based asynchronous processing NodeJS does. The client making an AJAX request doesn't care how the server produces the result. @Raynos Is there something usable like Twisted or EventMachine for PHP?

Comment: @Daff there should be something like node/twisted/eventmachine for PHP. However note that most web servers run PHP as CGI scripts with a one process per request model. You can't use PHP on a CGI based server and use something like twisted/eventmachine. You would basically have to write the web server in php.

Comment: Yeah that was what i was wondering. Doesn't sound like a trivial thing to do in PHP.